# How to iterate over document.body

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have to write `.getElementByClassName` from scratch. This is the code I have so far.

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className){
  let result = [];
  let bod = document.body;

  for (let prop in bod) {
    if (bod[prop].classList && bod[prop].classList.contains(className)) {
      result.push(bod[prop]);
    }
    let child = bod[prop].childNodes;
    for(let elem in child) {
      if (child[elem].classList.contains(className)) {
        result.push(child[elem]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

I can't access `document.body`. Is my syntax wrong or is a for loop not the way to go?

Comment: Are you sure `document.body` exists at the time you're trying to access it?

Comment: yes, its specified in the instructions

Comment: But have you implemented it in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prop in bod` will return even its methods/properties, and they don't have `classList`, only a `Node` has that.

Therefore, what you need is its child nodes, aka `document.body.childNodes`. Something like:

```
for (let i = 0; i<bod.childNodes.length; i++) {
  let thisNode = bod.childNodes[i];
  if (thisNode.classList) {
    // check if it has your class
  }
  if (thisNode.childNodes.length) {
    // go deeper in the node, recursively 
  }
}
```

And one loop is not enough, and you don't know how many you'll need, because each node can have any number of child nodes, so you'll need to do recursion.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. So I would need to recursively call `getElementsByClassName(document.body.childNodes)` and then run `.classList` on each one to see if it contains `className`?

Comment: something like that, yes - but you only need to do that if childNodes has more nodes, like I highlighted in my edit

Comment: In this case they do, I'm supposed to use recursion but I' terrible with it so I was trying to make it with a for loop first and then think of how to convert that to recusion

Answer (score 0):

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className){
  let result = [];
  let bod = document.body; // THis is not an object you can perform loop on.
```

It is better you do this

```
const BODY = document.querySelectorAll('body');

for(let prop in BODY) {
```

}